# making the y-axis text smaller in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code:

```
df5 %>%
  pivot_longer(-Varsta, names_to = "qnum") %>%
  left_join(questions2, by = "qnum") %>%
  ggplot(aes(value, qtxt2)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Varsta)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 5))`
```

and this plot
[image]

I am trying to make the text smaller and the graph bigger. How do you do that??

Comment: See the help page of the `theme` function. It should be `axis.text.y`, or something like that.

Comment: Try `ggplot(aes(value, str_wrap(qtxt2, 30)))` or another value than 30 that suits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reproducing the issue:

```
my_data <- data.frame(qtxt2 = paste(1:9, 
                                    "really long label that has many words that",
                                    "are taking up too much space in my plot"),
  value = runif(9, min = 1, max = 5))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(my_data, aes(value, qtxt2)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 5))
```

[image]

One solution is to shrink the y axis text:

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(value, qtxt2)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 5)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6))
```

[image]

It might be more effective here to use text wrapping to split the labels onto multiple lines.

```
my_data$qtxt3 = stringr::str_wrap(my_data$qtxt2, width = 30)
ggplot(my_data, aes(value, qtxt3)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 5))
```

[image]